# Errors installing Voyager in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, voyager, laravel-10

I've initiated a new Laravel 10 project and attempted to integrate Voyager. I executed the command:
`composer require tcg/voyager`

When that didn't work, I tried running `composer require tcg/voyager --with-all-dependencies`, but I encountered the same error. Could you help me understand what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it?

> Problem 1
> - tcg/voyager v0.11.14 requires illuminate/support ~5.3.0|~5.4.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.3.0, ..., v5.4.36] but
> these were not loaded, likely because it
> conflicts with another require.
> - tcg/voyager[v1.0.10, ..., v1.0.17] require illuminate/support ~5.4.0|~5.5.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.4.0,
> ..., v5.5.44] but these were not loaded, like
> ly because it conflicts with another require.
> - tcg/voyager[v1.1.0, ..., v1.1.3] require illuminate/support ~5.4.0|~5.5.0|~5.6.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.4.0, ..., v5.6.39]
> but these were not loaded,
> likely because it conflicts with another require.
> - tcg/voyager[v1.1.4, ..., v1.1.12] require illuminate/support ~5.4.0|~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~5.7.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.4.0, ...,
> v5.7.28] but these were not
> loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
> - tcg/voyager[v1.2.0, ..., v1.2.7] require illuminate/support ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~5.7.0|~5.8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ...,
> v5.8.36] but these were not
> loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
> - tcg/voyager[v1.3.0, ..., v1.3.2] require illuminate/support ~5.5|~6.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0,
> ..., v6.20.44] but these were
> not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
> - tcg/voyager[v1.4.0, ..., v1.4.2] require illuminate/support ~6.0|~7.0 -> found illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0,
> ..., v7.30.6] but these were
> not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
> - tcg/voyager[v1.4.3, ..., v1.5.2] require illuminate/support ~6.0|~7.0|~8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44,
> v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, .
> .., v8.83.27] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
> - tcg/voyager v1.6.0 requires illuminate/support ~8.0|~9.0 -> found illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.4]
> but these were not loaded,
> likely because it conflicts with another require.
> - Root composer.json requires tcg/voyager * -> satisfiable by tcg/voyager[v0.11.14, v1.0.10, ..., v1.6.0].
>
> ```
> You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require tcg/voyager:*" to figure
> ```
>
> out if any version is installable
> , or "composer require tcg/voyager:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Comment: That's not possible, see https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/5740

Comment: Always check the official documentation, or better: go to the official repo and read the `composer.json`, you will see if it is compatible or not....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voyager is not yet compatible with Laravel 10

[Voyager doc](https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/getting-started/prerequisites)

[Related issue on the repo](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/5740)

Comment: Just use 
composer require tcg/voyager dev-1.6-l10

It's worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Now they have added the support for Laravel 10. In official git says that this command is working

```
composer require tcg/voyager dev-1.6-l10
```

Here is the [link](https://github.com/thedevdojo/voyager) to voyager github.